# Binding from resources inside a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, resources, datatemplate

Is there some way to get the `DataContext` of a `DataTemplate` to use in bindings within its resources?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="History">
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding History}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
      <app:BitmapProvider x:Key="Converter" ShowDetails="True"
                          Type="{Binding Model.Type}" />
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Image Source="{Binding Data, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

The above template is used as the `CellTemplate` of a `ListBox`.  The object at that level has two properties, `History` (containing a list of "historic info" objects) and `Model` (containing a bunch of other stuff, including `Type`).  I'm using an `ItemsControl` to display the historic items next to each other; I want to display an image for each one, and the image is obtained from the `BitmapProvider`, which is an `IValueConverter`.

The converter needs two bits of info to obtain a result: one is the `Data` of the individual historic items, and the other is the `Type` of the whole collection.  An added complication is that constructing this particular converter (or changing the `Type` given to it) is expensive, so I don't want to put it at the level of the individual history item, or to use a `MultiBinding`, and I can't put it outside of the template because then it won't have access to the `Type`.

Unfortunately, the above gives me the following error:

*System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Model.Type; DataItem=null; target element is 'BitmapProvider' (HashCode=57142809); target property is 'Type' (type 'TypeDetails')*

Which I understand to mean that the resource can't figure out how to get the `DataContext` of the element it's contained within.

(I have searched, and most of the answers I could find suggested moving it outside the template or using a `MultiBinding` instead -- neither of which would really work in this case, as far as I can tell, as I've explained above.  But I'd be delighted to be proven wrong, or given another alternative.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can accomplish that with [DataContextSpy](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ArtificialInheritanceCxt.aspx).

try something like:

```
<ItemsControl.Resources>
  <spy:DataContextSpy x:Key="Spy"/>
  <app:BitmapProvider x:Key="Converter" ShowDetails="True"
                      Type="{Binding DataContext.Model.Type,Source={StaticResource Spy}}" />
</ItemsControl.Resources>
```

Comment: That's new to me too.  But it works.  Thanks!  (I am still considering a different solution: extracting the expensive part into a separate class hosted by the collection's ViewModel, and make the converter use that and the item's Data to get its result.  But I don't like that as much because it feels too much like polluting the ViewModel with too much View-specific data -- I like being able to share a ViewModel between multiple Views.)

Comment: don't worry about this being some kind of hack! If you look at that article's date (July 2008) you see it's been around for a while. The other very useful class is [ElementSpy](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/07/22/enable-elementname-bindings-with-elementspy/). Keep that on your list of useful WPF helpers too!

Comment: Yeah, ElementSpy looks good too.  I used to use Dr.WPF's ObjectReferenceExtension for that purpose (which unfortunately uses static data, limiting its usefulness), until I discovered the PlacementTarget trick, which so far has been sufficient.  But it's good to have something to fall back to if I need something that PlacementTarget won't work for.